# Can't execute PHP script using php exec() (in magento)

Tags: php, magento, exec

I want some php script to be launching in a background proccess. For this i have a special method in my class

```
protected function _runSpider()
{
    $php = exec('which php');
    $result = exec($php . ' ' . Mage::getBaseDir() . '/spider.php > ' . Mage::getBaseDir() . '/var/log/out.log 2>&1 &');
    Mage::log($result);
}
```

this should execute something like this

```
/usr/bin/php /home/www/spider.php > home/www/var/log/out.log 2>&1 &
```

But in result as i think script is not executing, magento log is empty and `out.log` file is empty.

Comment: Do you have safe mode enabled?

Comment: Also check if "exec" is disabled on your host - do you see it in the list returned by: ini_get('disable_functions')

Comment: exec('which php') works good, safe mode is disabled

Comment: If out.log exists but is empty then it must have been created by the pipe command but the spider outputs nothing. Check that it is running by having it modify a file directly.

Comment: Have you tried to run this script outside of magento, from another simple php script? Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
protected function _runSpider()
    {
        $command = '$(which php) ' . Mage::getBaseDir() . '/spider.php > ' . Mage::getBaseDir() . '/var/log/out.log');
        $result = exec($command);
        Mage::log($result);
    }
```

Removing the last & will lock execution of the script instead of passing control back to the interpreter. And since you're piping all of the output to a file, maybe you don't need to pipe the output to `null`.

By the way, the shell command you mounted won't return any data as you're piping everything to a file or /dev/null. If you need it back to the `$result` var, remove the `> filename` part of the code, though exec will only [give you the last line of the result](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and you may need the [passthru()](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) function or add an `$output` var to store every line to an array on the `exec` function.